# Firebase Database - DataSnapshot getValue(MODEL.class) with proguard always gets null attribute

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To avoid misleading to think, re-edit the question.

Firebase Database `DataSnapshot getValue(TimeSlot.class)` always return `null`, but getValue toString still show correct attributes values, Did any one have such experience?

**Update the question:**

**This problem happened when I enable proguard**

When I add -keep data mode class in proguard file, this issue is fixed.

Comment: can you include `TimeSlot` code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this rule to `proguard-rules.pro` file

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.app.models.** {
  *;
}
```

Change `com.example.app.models` to your `TimeSlot` class package

Reference [Set up Firebase Realtime Database for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)